# Java framework for text- & console-based forms?

Tags: java, forms, ncurses, vt100

Are there any Java-based frameworks for defining and managing text-, VT100- or console-based forms systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give a try to:

- [charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/)
- [jcurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)
- [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/), a 100% Java way to bind C functions

Answer (score 5):

I've just found [Lanterna](http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) which is actively developed.

Comment: This actually works really well, has the advantage that it is pure java